# How to get client secret from existing Azure service principal

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I have created a RBAC enabled [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest) in Azure to configure Key Vault access within my OS using environment variables. When you create a service principal, the Azure CLI responds with the service principal details, containing the `clientSecret` value. Creation command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n <http://my-name> --sdk-auth
```

I would like to know if and how I can request the `clientSecret` later on. When I use

```
az ad sp show --id <my-service-principal-uuid>
```

or

```
az ad sp credential list --id <my-service-principal-uuid>
```

the `clientSecret` is not in the response information.

Is there any way to retrieve the `clientSecret` other than at the moment of creation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot retrieve it after creation. The best you can do is to reset it, at which point you will be shown the new value:

```
PS C:\> az ad sp credential reset --name foo
{
  "appId": "...",
  "name": "foo",
  "password": "...",
  "tenant": "..."
}
```

This means that you will need to update the credential manually wherever you've made use of it, for example in Azure DevOps if you've created an Azure RM service connection with that particular service principal.

Answer (score 0):

You can get like below

## Create a service principal

```
SPA_SP_APP_ID=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $AKS_SP_NAME --skip-assignment --query appId)
```

## Retrieve Service principal APPID and Client Secret

```
 SPA_SP_SECRET=$(az ad sp credential reset --name $SPA_SP_APP_ID --query "password")
```

**EDIT**

As Moss Mentioned above, you cannot retrieve once it is created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this method resets and returns a NEW clientSecret, while I am looking for the existing clientSecret

Comment: you cant retrieve it

Comment: The second command should be `--id` instead of `--name`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a client secret visible in **Azure Portal > Entra ID (Active Directory) > App Registrations > sp-name > Certificates & Secrets > Client Secrets**

Then you need to use this command

```
 az ad app credential reset --id ${CLIENT_ID}
```

The `az ad sp` command makes different secrets.

```
az ad app credential list --id ${CLIENT_ID}
az ad sp credential list --id ${CLIENT_ID}
```